# Can I find Fermat's complete works anywhere?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ho.history-overview, books

I admire the mathematician very much and want to look at his writings.  Is there anywhere in book or web form that has a collection of his writings?

Answer (score 17):

The collected works of Fermat were published by Tannery and Henry, taken from http://www.fermat-science.com/pierre-fermat/ses-oeuvres/ here are the details:

> [H.T. 1891], Oeuvres de Fermat, t. I, Œuvres mathématiques diverses – Observations sur Diophante, éd. P. Tannery et C. Henry, Paris, Gauthier-Villars, 1891.
>
> [H.T. 1894], Oeuvres de Fermat, t. II, Correspondance, éd. P. Tannery et C. Henry, Paris, Gauthier-Villars, 1894.
>
> [H.T. 1896], Oeuvres de Fermat, t. III, Traductions des écrits latins de Fermat ; de l’Inventum novum de J. de Billy ; du Commercium epistolicum de Wallis par P. Tannery, éd. P. Tannery et C. Henry, Paris, Gauthier-Villars, 1896.
>
> [H.T. 1912], Oeuvres de Fermat, t. IV, Compléments par P. Tannery, éd. P. Tannery et C. Henry, Paris, Gauthier-Villars, 1912.
>
> [H.T. 1922], Oeuvres de Fermat, supp. T. I-IV par M. C. de Waard, éd. P. Tannery et C. Henry, Paris, Gauthier-Villars, 1922.

The books seem out of print, but free (and given the age of the book likely even legal) can be found on the web, for example on the Internet Archive: archive.org.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the letters  [here.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5188175/oeuvresdefermat.pdf)

Comment: Sadly, I don't read french :(